Is there a limit to the size of a path list that can be used in a DataFrameReader
I am doing
df = spark.read.option("wholetext", "true").text(list_of_paths)

Are there any limitations on this list size?
Note, I am aware this might not be efficient, but it is my most efficient option given the scenario

You can move your files into a separete folder and then read from the folder.

True, did not think of a non-spark solution for some reason. Thanks!

You can read a folder with millions of files in spark. Just provide the folder path. You then need not worry about list of files.

Files are in different prefixes / "folders" with no common parent / bucket
